# How to get one or more elements with a given ID and process once at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

We have elements with a wrapper class below that will contain an element with a specific ID and data attribute (see below). There can be 0-N (where N is some number like 5) number of wrapper classes.

How can we retrieve all of the wrapper class (0-N) and change the data attribute values if the children contain an element where the element's id contains 'id_'?

```js
$(function() {
  $('.wrapper__class').each(function(index) {
    /* 
    1. get all children where children's id contains "id_"
    2. get parent
    3. update parent's data-processed from 0 to 1
    */
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper__class" data-processed="0">
  <div class="inner__class" id="id_123">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper__class" data-processed="0">
  <div class="inner__class" id="id_345">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper__class" data-processed="0">
  <div class="inner__class" id="id_567">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper__class" data-processed="0">
  <div class="inner__class" id="id_789">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper__class" data-processed="0">
  <div class="inner__class" id="id_101">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this selector:** `.wrapper__class:has(div.inner__class[id^="id_"])`

```js
$(function() {
  $('.wrapper__class:has(div.inner__class[id^="id_"])').data("processed", "1"); 
  // Just to illustrate
  $('.wrapper__class').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).data('processed'))
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper__class" data-processed="0">
  <div class="inner__class" id="id_123">a
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper__class" data-processed="0">
  <div class="inner__class" id="id_345">b
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper__class" data-processed="0">
  <div class="inner__class" id="id567">c
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper__class" data-processed="0">
  <div class="inner__class" id="id_789">d
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper__class" data-processed="0">
  <div class="inner__class" id="id_101">e
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the "attribute starts with" selector.

Based on your description, it sounds like maybe you actually just want this:

```
$(function() {
  $('.wrapper__class').each(function(index, el) {
    el.dataset.processed = el.querySelectorAll("[id^=id_]").length;
  });
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('.wrapper__class').each(function(index, el) {
    el.dataset.processed = el.querySelectorAll("[id^=id_]").length;
    console.log(el.dataset.processed);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper__class" data-processed="0">
  <div class="inner__class" id="id_123">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper__class" data-processed="0">
  <div class="inner__class" id="id_345">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper__class" data-processed="0">
  <div class="inner__class" id="id_567">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper__class" data-processed="0">
  <div class="inner__class" id="id_789">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper__class" data-processed="0">
  <div class="inner__class" id="id_101">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Removing the rest of the jQuery and adding arrow functions, we get this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper__class').forEach(el => {
    el.dataset.processed = el.querySelectorAll("[id^=id_]").length;
  });
});
```